# How to deploy and debug a Windows Phone 8.1 app from a Hyper-V guest machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I use a Hyper-V VM to run Visual Studio, but this VM cannot see my Windows Phone device connected to the host computer. Both guest and host run Windows 8.1 Enterprise and on "This PC", in the guest machine, I can see a MTP Device representing my Windows Phone, but no content is displayed. On the host, a Windows Phone icon is displayed and I have access to media content. Is there a way to make Visual Studio 2013 on this guest machine connect to the device the same way the host would do?

All I want is to deploy and debug the app I am building from the Hyper-V guest to my physical Windows Phone device.